# System.UnauthorizedAccessException Message=Access to the path "/C:\Users\user\Desktop\C\dok.txt" is denied

Tags: c#, csv, txt, writeallbytes

I'm trying to export data to PC local drive from a C# xamarin app. Even as an administrator, I have the same problem as in the title, no matter if the file exist or not...
code below, x,y are List :

```
        var csv = new StringBuilder();

        for (int i = 0; i < x.Count; i++)
        {

            var first = x[i].ToString();
            var second = y[i].ToString();
            var newLine = string.Format("{0}  - {1}", first, second);
            csv.AppendLine(newLine);

        }

        byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(csv.ToString());
        File.WriteAllBytes(@"C:\Users\user\Desktop\C\" + "dok.txt", data);
```

Comment: Is the user's name user?

Comment: Hi, please let me know where i can check it ? I did not change anything so maybe yes, user's name is user.

Comment: It would be the name of the user account you used to log on to the machine.  You can also check c:\users to see if there is indeed a ./user subdirectory there.

Comment: Hi, yes, so user's name is user, what next ? ;)

Comment: I think you'll find that if you try to go to that subdirectory as another user with Explorer (even as Administrator) you'll get a prompt for permissions.  I suspect that's what you're seeing.  Beyond using another subdirectory, I don't know how (or if) apps handle this situation.

Comment: Thanks, in my xamarin app i just want to save some  data on my PC from c# calculation, do you know how to do this in simply way ?

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with the Xamarin platform and environment to answer.